# SSRS graphs X-axis display 30 min interval

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS graph that has X-axis values as follows 00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, 02:00, 02:30....23:30 but as shown in the image below graph only shows 04:30, 09:30, 14:30, 19:30. How do I show them all. Query returns the data in HH:mm format. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FIgured it out. horizontal axis  -> axis type =category

> ```
>     Interval = 1
>
>     Interval type= Number
> ```